# A strange characterisation of cyclic groups

Tags: group-theory

"A ﬁnite group is cyclic if, for any integer m, the number of elements 
of order dividing m is at most m."

I have never seen this characterisation of cyclic groups before. How do I prove this? I hope the proof isn't too complicated because it's a lemma in another proof.

Comment: This is usually part of the proof that any finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field is cyclic, but it stands on its own, though you may argue it's not too natural. See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/59911/589.

Comment: Someone has also asked the question without the field theory context [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346936/finite-cyclic-group).