# What is the meaning of $\bigsqcup$?

Tags: group-theory

This is the expression: $$G=\bigsqcup_{d\mid n}X_d$$
I saw it here - [Finite group for which $|\{x:x^m=e\}|\leq m$ for all $m$ is cyclic.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346936/finite-group-for-which-xxm-e-leq-m-for-all-m-is-cyclic)

Thank you!

Comment: It usually means "disjoint union".

Comment: e.g. $\left\{1,2,3\right\}\cup\left\{4,5,6\right\}$?

Comment: Well, in curly brackets, but yes. $\{1, 2, 3\}\bigsqcup\{4, 5, 6\}$ but **not** $\{1, 2, 3\}\bigsqcup\{3, 4, 5, 6\}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually it means disjoint (pairwise). Others write $\biguplus$.

Answer (score 4):

It means that the sets $X_d$ in the union are pairwise disjoint.